# A wrong proof about $G_{\delta}$ set

Tags: real-analysis

It's well known that not all sets in $R$ are $G_{\delta}$ set, and I have a wrong "proof" to show every set in $R$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set, can you tell me where I went wrong? Thank you.

To a set $S$ in $R$, to any x$\in S$, I we have the NBHD of x with radius 1/n:  $b_{1/n}(x)$, and define the set $B_{1/n}$ by the union of all $b_{1/n}(x)$ with x$\in$S, which is open. Then the countable intersection of {$B_{1/n}$} is just S since the countable intersection of {$b_{1/n}(x)$} is just x.

Comment: The intersection is $\overline{S}$ (the closure of $S$), not $S$.

Comment: To expand on the comment by Brandon, let $S$ be the set of reciprocals of the positive integers, Then $0$ is in every $B_{1/n}$.

Comment: @Brandon thanks

Comment: It gives a counterexample to the assertion that the countable intersection is $S$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection does not give the original set. For example, take $S = \Bbb{Q}$ then $B_\varepsilon$ is whole $\Bbb{R}$ whatever $\varepsilon>0$ is. In general you can check that the closure of $S$ is contained in the intersection (just take some sequence converging to $x\in\overline{S}$). In fact, the intersection of $S_{1/n}$ is the closure of $S$.

Your proof can be applied to proving that every *closed* set is $G_\delta$, though not every set is $G_\delta$.